How to use "createCookies(req)" function of VueUse in SSR mode with Laravel/Inertia backend?
I want to have a theme cookie where I save the current theme. I'm using VueUse's useCookies to do it on SPA mode, but it fails on SSR mode. The documentation says I need to use createCookies function instead an pass in my node request object which is of type IncomingMessage. But the problem is I'm using Laravel/Inertia and don't know what to pass in or how. Here's the code I'm using:
// AppLayout.vue
import { useThemes } from '@/stores/useThemes'
const themes = useThemes()

// useThemes.ts
import { createCookies, useCookies } from '@vueuse/integrations/useCookies'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export type Theme = string

export const useThemes = defineStore('themes', () => {
    const cookies = useCookies(['theme'])

    const theme = ref(cookies.get('theme') || 'default')

    /**
     * @field General themes
     */
    const generalThemes: Theme[] = ['Default', 'Light', 'Dark']

    /**
     * @field Light themes
     */
    const lightThemes: Theme[] = [
        'Cupcake',
        'Corporate',
        'Fantasy',
        'Autumn',
        'Winter',
        'Limonade',
        'Garden',
        'Retro',
        'Cyberpunk',
        'Valentine',
        'Nord',
    ]

    /**
     * @field Dark themes
     */
    const darkThemes: Theme[] = ['Coffee', 'Aqua', 'Night', 'Sunset', 'Halloween', 'Business']

    /**
     * Set theme by string name
     * @param {string} lang Language to be set
     */
    function setTheme(themeName: string) {
        if (
            themeName != null &&
            themeName != undefined &&
            themeName.trim() != '' &&
            (generalThemes.includes(capitalize(themeName)) ||
                lightThemes.includes(capitalize(themeName)) ||
                darkThemes.includes(capitalize(themeName)))
        ) {
            theme.value = themeName
            cookies.set('theme', theme.value)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capitalize a string's first letter
     * @param {string} value String to be capitalized
     */
    function capitalize(value: string): string {
        return value
            .split(' ')
            .map((word) => {
                return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)
            })
            .join(' ')
    }

    /**
     * Initialize theme if not set
     */
    function initTheme() {
        console.log(theme.value)
        setTheme(theme.value)
    }

    return { theme, initTheme, setTheme, generalThemes, lightThemes, darkThemes }
})

The line const cookies = useCookies(['theme']) throws error in SSR mode (Cookie is not defined in useCookies()) and must be replaced by createCookies. Here's the Laravel side:
// PageController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class PageController extends Controller {
    public function home(Request $req): \Inertia\Response {
        return Inertia::render('Home', [
            'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
            'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
            'themeCookie' => $req->cookie('theme') ?? 'default',
            'animatedCookie' => boolval($req->cookie('animated')) ?? true,
        ]);
    }
}

Note that VueUse's useCookies uses universal-cookie package internally.

"throws error in SSR mode" - which error?

@EstusFlask says Cookie is not defined in useCookies()
